# Python eigenvalue computations run much slower than those of MATLAB on my computer. Why?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, eigenvalue

I would like to compute the eigenvalues of large-ish matrices (about 1000x1000) using Python 2.6.5. I have been unable to do so quickly. I have not found any other threads addressing this question.

When I run

```
a = rand(1000,1000);
tic;
for i =1:10
    eig(a);
end
toc;
```

in MATLAB it takes about 30 seconds. A similar test in Python requires 216 seconds. Running it through R using RPy did not speed up the computation appreciably. A test in Octave took 93 seconds. I am a bit baffled at the difference in speed.

The only instance of a question like this one I can find online is [this](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/436535/), which is several years old. The poster in that question has a different Python directory structure (which I attribute to the age of the post, although I could be mistaken), so I have not been confident enough to attempt to follow the instructions posted by the correspondent.

My package manager says that I have LAPACK installed, and I am using NumPy and SciPy for the Python calculations:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy import *
from numpy.linalg import *
import time

a = randn(1000,1000)
tic = time.clock()
for i in range(0,10):
    eig(a)
toc = time.clock()
print "Elapsed time is ", toc-tic
```

I am pretty new to Python, so I may have done something silly. Please let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Comment: Are you using the same precision in Python and Matlab?

Comment: You do need to make sure your indentation in your Python code is exactly correct.  Your example can't run as written.

Comment: Just to let you know you should use `rand` for both (uniform distribution) or `randn` (normal distribution) but not mix them. This does not explain the difference though.

Comment: What would the timings be with `svd`? Also, please reformat your code properly, don't import something you are not using and please try to avoid idiom `from . import *`. Thanks

Comment: I have tried `svd` (3 seconds *without the loop*)  and `eigvals` (12 seconds), to be compared to 30 seconds with `eig`. Although, with `svd`, you only get the singular values of a'*a, not a.

Comment: I meant the square roots of the eigenvalues of a'*a.

Answer (score 15):

I think what you're seeing is the difference between the Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL)  that's being used by Matlab and whatever LAPACK implementation you have on your system (ATLAS, maybe?) that scipy is linked against. You can see how much faster the MKL is in [these benchmarks](http://www.enthought.com/epd/mkl/).

I imagine that you would get much better performance if you could rebuild Scipy against the Intel MKL libraries. If you're using Windows, pre-built copies can be downloaded from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), or you might consider using something like the Enthought Python Distribution.

Comment: That's certainly a large part of it.  Comparing `np.linalg.eig` on a version of numpy using ATLAS vs one linked against the MKL results in a roughly 3-fold difference on my machine for an array of the OP's size. (10.1 sec vs 3.2 sec)

Answer (score 3):

I do get a difference in timings, but not as drastic as yours. My `MATLAB` (R2010b) timing was ~25 seconds and `python` (2.7) timing was ~60 seconds.

I'm not really surprised by these numbers as `MATLAB` is solely a numerical and matrix manipulation language, and it has the advantage of its `JIT` accelerator over `python`, which is a general purpose language. Generally, the differences between `MATLAB` and `python+numpy` are quite small, but become apparent when the matrix size is large, as in your case.

That doesn't mean there aren't ways to improve python's performance. The [PerformancePython](http://wiki.scipy.org/PerformancePython) article on scipy's website gives a good introduction to the different ways in which you can improve the performance of python.